# My Linked List does not print out from the beginning

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

The problem I am having with my program is that I create a linked list, but when I go to print out my linked list it just prints out the last person in the list. It is supposed to print out everyone in the list. This is the only problem that I have in my program and if someone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_PLAYERS 9
#define MAX_STR_LEN 25

typedef struct Player_ {
    char name[MAX_STR_LEN];
    int number_of_hits;
    int number_of_strikes;
    struct Player_ *next;
} Player;

int pitch_result(void);
Player *add_player(Player *first_player, const char *name);
void destroy_team(Player *first_player);
void display_line_up(Player* first);
void readFile(Player **lineup, const char* file);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc < 2){
        exit(1);
    }
    srand(time(NULL));
    int strikes = 0;
    int hits = 0;
    Player *lineup = NULL;
    readFile(&lineup, argv[1]);
    printf("\nLine up for this team is: ");
    display_line_up(lineup);

    printf("\n\n%s is batting \n", lineup->name);

    for ( ; strikes < 3; ) {
        int result = pitch_result();
        if (result) {
            ++hits;
        }
        else
            ++strikes;
    }

    printf("\nScore of game was: %d\n", hits/4);
    return 0;
}

void readFile(Player **lineup, const char* file){
    FILE *input;
    input = fopen(file, "r");
    if(input == NULL){
        printf("Failed to open");
    }
    char player[MAX_STR_LEN];
    while(fscanf(input, "%s", &player) != EOF){
        //      printf("\n%s", player);
        *lineup = add_player(*lineup, player);
    }
}

int pitch_result(void) {
    int result;
    result = rand() % 2;
    return result;
}

void destroy_team(Player *first_player){
    Player *temp = first_player->next;
    Player *free_player;

    while (temp) {
        free_player = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        free(free_player->name);
        free(free_player);
    }
}

Player *add_player(Player *first_player, const char *name) {
    Player *new_player = (Player*)malloc(sizeof(Player));

    int nameLength;
    nameLength = strlen(name);

    // new_player->name = malloc(nameLength * sizeof(char));

    new_player->next = NULL;

    strncpy(new_player->name, name, nameLength);
    new_player->number_of_hits = 0;
    new_player->number_of_strikes = 0;

    return new_player;
}

void display_line_up(Player *first){

    if(first == NULL)
        printf("\nThe list is empty");
    else {
        while(first != NULL){
            printf("\n%s", first->name);
            first = first->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the file that I read into the program when I run it (stats.txt)

```
Yadier_Molina
Allen_Craig
Daniel_Descalso
Rafael_Furcal
David_Freese
Matt_Holiday
Jon_Jay
Carlos_Beltran
Matt_Adams
```

This is the sample output that I was given for my program

```
Line up for this team is:   

Yadier_Molina   
Allen_Craig 
Daniel_Descalso 
Rafael_Furcal   
David_Freese    
Matt_Holliday   
Jon_Jay 
Carlos_Beltran  
Matt_Adams  
Yadier_Molina   is  batting 
Strike! 
hit!    
Strike! 
Strike! 

Score   of  game    was:    0
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `add_player` function returns a pointer to a node that contains the new player-- and has no connection to the preexisting list (the variable `first_player` is never even used).

Your `readFile` function uses this, discarding the old list each time it reads the name of a new player:

```
*lineup = add_player(*lineup, player);
```

so the resultant list contains only the last player.

Comment: Looks like a memory leak.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: It is a memory leak, but worse than that it's a loss of data.

Answer (score 0):

As Beta said, you are not concatenating the players to the list. You can keep a pointer to the last element, which you modify from `readFile`:

```
void readFile(Player **lineup, const char* file){
    Player* last = NULL;
    FILE *input;
    input = fopen(file, "r");
    if(input == NULL){
        printf("Failed to open");
    }
    char player[MAX_STR_LEN];
    while(fscanf(input, "%s", &player) != EOF){
        //      printf("\n%s", player);
        Player* p = add_player(player);
        if (!last)
          *lineup = p;
        else 
          last->next = p;
        last = p;
    }
}
```

And the function add_player just creates a new player so, I would rename it to: `create_player(const char* name)`